# Finding line intersections with some tolerance?

Tags: python, algorithm

I want to find if 2 people are meeting or not, so from the points given for each person I make a path and see if it intersects (using sharply),

```
line1 = LineString(verts_1)
line2 = LineString(verts_2)
return line1.intersection(line2)
```

The problem is:

1. I need to know exactly which line segment has intersected or approximately intersected (if distance between lines is lesser than a threshold). For efficient intersection I can also use the Bentley Ottman algorithm (CGAL) for efficiency but again I have the same problem.
2. I also need to find how far the intersection or pseudo intersection(the closest point between both the line segments on each line) is from the 2 ends of each line segment (I need to interpolate the time when they met).

Any help, code snippets or algorithms advice is welcome. The language I am using is python and my data is quite large so I need it to be efficient.

Thank you!

EDIT: The points are sampled irregularly, some very close some very far apart.

Comment: If the frequency with which the points are collected is *high enough* you do not have to build lines and check for intersections; you can use the points directly.

Comment: Maybe you could use the snap function to perform a snap with a given tolerance ? https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/blob/master/docs/manual.rst#snapping

Comment: @Ev.Kounis edited the question

Comment: Fatten lines to rectangles representing the threshold around the lines then search for intersecting rectangles - i.e. if any of the four line segments of one rectangle intersect any of the four line segments representing the fattened second line segment.

Comment: @Paddy3118 thats an awesome idea! Im going to try it out and get back to you!